# Files hosted on HTTP server will not download correctly to android

Tags: php, android, http, xhtml

I am trying to host an assortment of multimedia files on an http server for convenience (I need to test an assortment of phones for multimedia compatibility in the web browser and natively). However, many of the files I put up will not download and/or stream correctly.

(Note: I'm using `<a src="whatever.mp3">......</a>` to include the file links on an XHTML page)

For example, **Android supports both AMR-NB and AMR-WB**. AMR-NB files (.amr) stream and download correctly, however **AMR-WB files (.awb) when clicked on will open as plain text or save as .txt files**. Is there any way I can make the phone recognize these filetypes properly (either through android, or even better, with an **web-based fix**)?

**Other files that I'm having problems with include .dm files** (DRM Forward Locked Media - these download and work properly with Blackberry, but not Android, however an older content site I use, the .dm files work on Android - I can't figure out any difference with the source code)

(Note: If it matters, the server is a private intranet for my company)

Answer (score 1):

What are you using as a server?

You might have to add MIME types declarations for each of the file types that you are using in order to get it working

Answer (score 0):

Instead of direct links to a files create a download script that will get the file, check for its size and `mime_type` and will echo the file contents with header `Content-Type` set accordingly...